# Do you need a decoupling capacitor for an RC servo connector?

Tags: servo, decoupling-capacitor

I have watched a lengthy youtube video about decoupling capacitors and how you should use them.

I am in doubt if you should add decoupling capacitors in front of 3p connectors for RC servo motors such as an MG90.

The reason why I am in doubt: There is like 30cm of wire between the board and the servo. That 30cm wire has inductance. I can imagine this is alot. And you want the capacitor to be as close to where the power is consumed. Somewhere on the PCB inside the motor.

If the servo already has a decoupler capacitor over VCC and GND internally. Does an external one which is 30cm behind inductive wires still going to do any good or does is it not going to make a difference?

Comment: Not normally. No. But you can. Decoupling caps for low frequencies are less sensitive to location since inductance has lower impedance at lower frequencies. Lower frequencies tend to contain more energy though so the capacitors for lower frequencies tends to be larger. So if it's 30cm away for it to be useful it's probably going to have to be 100uF or even 470uF, but at 30cm I wouldn't bother.

Comment: That video was quite specific that the frequency was not a big deal but the rise and fall times were. He demonstrated by controlling a mosfet using a slow opamp and an arduino pin. The pin had a rise time of a few nano seconds causing a voltage dip to 3.5V from a 9V rails. The opamp with a rise time of a few microseconds was so slow that a capacitor was hardly needed. The mosfet was fed with a servo signal. It switched 1 amp for 2ms: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARwBwHZESOY